# Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference error when migrating my Joomla website from Apache to NginX

Tags: php, apache, nginx, joomla, uri

I'm getting this error when I serve my Joomla on `server_name www.domain.com`. No error if I serve the same Joomla directory with `server_name test.domain.com`

I have a production server that is on an AWS EC2 instance and run smoothly the last years under Apache web server and I'm trying to migrate the whole Joomla installation to be served by an NginX/PHP container on a different environment.

So I just got the files and the database and start testing. Everything was fine when I was testing on www.dev.domain.com (development environment as well to test.domain.com (production environment).

The problem popped up when I changed to www.domain.com
I've tried different server_names.
I've tried to serve an index.html file instead of my original index.php file and works fine even if I place it at the end of the URL manually or even if I set it into my nginx.conf as index;
Joomla backend (administration) works fine on www.domain.com/administrator
I tried `server_name domain.com www.domain.com test.domain.com;` into my configuration but only test.domain.com was functional.

*In cases with no error, the site is fully functional

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com test.domain.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    access_log /logs/access.log;
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    return 404;
            }
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            server_tokens off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the site to run smoothly with no issues as it was served fine under test.domain.com server_name but I got the error bellow:

> 0 Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference Please try one of the following
>   pages: HOME PAGE

Comment: If you don't receive any support here, you might post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.
There was a published Virtual Domain into my Joomla installation. A setting configured from my predecessor system administrator or maybe my company's web developers.
So, I unpublished that through my.domain.com/administrator console components->Virtual Domains and everything went smooth as well with my 
`server_name www.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade Virtual Domains component for Joomla from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2.
1.3.2 version works with PHP7.